# Is it Possible to use "event rating" in Universal Template

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, mahout, predictionio

i have event like below :

```
{
  "event": "rate",
  "entityType": "user",
  "entityId": "John",
  "targetEntityType": "item",
  "targetEntityId": "Car Toy",
  "properties" : 
   {
     "rating" : 5
   } 
}
```

i want the event "rate" that have properties "rating" to be calculated using current **(UR) algorithm** in [Prediction.io Universal Template](https://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation). Is it possible ? or i need to use ALS algorithm and add it as multiple algorithm ?

Comment: hey, might want to check out this post on the pio google group
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/predictionio-user/WM4dzlm4S7I/jcxd-N1BEAAJ